# How to get the value based on the selected option value

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4, whmcs

I have the following php code and get the api data from whmcs. This code returns the product name value.

```
<select id="ssl" class="form-control select_plan" style="width:95%">
    <option value="--Select--">--Select--</option>
        @foreach($products['products']['product'] as $key)
            @if($key['gid'] == '10')
               <option value="{{$key['name']}}">{{$key['name']}}</option>
            @endif
        @endforeach
</select>
```

This code returns the product price value

```
@foreach($products['products']['product'] as $key)
        @if($key['gid'] == '10')
            @foreach($key['pricing'] as $value)
                @if($key['name']=='Positive SSL Wildcard')
                    {{$value['annually']}}
                @endif
            @endforeach
        @endif
    @endforeach
```

Here mentioned my response data from whmcs. Please find the data and suggest any solution

```
 Array
         (
        [pid] => 31
        [gid] => 10
        [type] => hostingaccount
        [name] => Comodo PositiveSSL
        [description] => 

        Domain Validation

        1 Domain

        Free additional server licenses

        Issued within 2 days


        [module] => GGSSLWHMCS
        [paytype] => recurring
        [pricing] => Array
            (
                [INR] => Array
                    (
                        [prefix] => ₹
                        [suffix] => INR
                        [msetupfee] => 0.00
                        [qsetupfee] => 0.00
                        [ssetupfee] => 0.00
                        [asetupfee] => 0.00
                        [bsetupfee] => 0.00
                        [tsetupfee] => 0.00
                        [monthly] => -1.00
                        [quarterly] => -1.00
                        [semiannually] => -1.00
                        [annually] => 100.00
                        [biennially] => 200.00
                        [triennially] => -1.00
                    )

            )

        [customfields] => Array
            (
                [customfield] => Array
                    (
                    )

            )

        [configoptions] => Array
            (
                [configoption] => Array
                    (
                    )

            )

    )
```

If i select one product name it doesn't display the corresponding price value of the product.Please suggest any solution.

Comment: show ur response data

Comment: I have edit the question please find the response data from whmcs

Comment: `{{$value['INR']['annually']}}` TRY

Comment: I can get the pricing value that's not a problem. But when I select the option value know to get the corresponding price value of that product. Because I have 82 products same as the above response data. Please suggest any solution

Comment: i think u want to change the response structure to another format such as (key and value pair). So that u can easily parse it.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly change

```
<option value="$key['name']">$key['name']</option>
```

to

```
<option value="{{ $key['name'] }}"> {{ $key['name'] }} </option>
```

Comment: please find the question Changed the option value

Answer (score 0):

use jquery as follows:

`$("#ss1 option:selected").val();`

Comment: Why jQuery? What does this accomplish? Please explain why your answer solves OP's question.

Comment: he wants selected option value from that dropdown right. it gives correct output. So many times i used in real time. Thats y i shared from my side.